# Destroy Iframe Player in Win8 App

Tags: youtube-api

I'm embedding the iframe player in a Win8 metro app and want to remove the player when a video is not being played.

The code that I'm currently using to do this is:

```
player.stopVideo();
player.destroy();
player = null;
```

And I continue getting an error that makes it seem like scripts are still running on the player afterwards.

Moreover, I get an error that the Javascript Array identifier and the isNaN identifier are undefined.

Am I using the destroy API correctly, and are there any possible reasons that this strange error may be occurring?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like is needed a trick  to resolve this problem:

http://markmail.org/message/cluuupb5nf34rooi